# Not able to parse data from HTML form to PDF using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

i m in a situation where i need to transfer a data when submitted on HTML form to update in MYSQL database and generate pdf for that data submitted. This must also contain the increment values like generating receipt number.

My pdf code is here scripted in php.

```
<?php

require('fpdf.php');

    class PDF extends FPDF
{
//Page header
function Header()
{

    //Move to the right
    $this->Cell(130);
    //Title
    include('connection.php');
    mysql_select_db("inventory") or die("Couldn't find db");
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sold WHERE imei = '6135352313'");//This is where i need help how to get data from the HTML form after updating in MYSQL
    while ($result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{

    $this->Cell(50,10,'CP '.$result1["receiptnumber"],1,1,'C'); //receipt number to be pulled from Auto_increment field in database
    }
    //Move to the right
    $this->Cell(130);
    //Date
    $this->Cell(50,10,date("l F dS Y "),1,0,'C');
    //Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

//Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    include('connection.php');
    mysql_select_db("inventory") or die("Couldn't find db");
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sold WHERE imei = '6135352313'"); //This is where i need help how to get data from the HTML form after updating in MYSQL

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{

    //Move to the right
    $pdf->Cell(50,5,'Invoice To ',0,0,'R');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    $pdf->Cell(140,8,$result["firstname"]." ".$result["lastname"],1,1,'C');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);

    }
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: @tomalak-geretkal my question is to get the data from HTML form to update in mysql to a unique indentifier and generate pdf with that unique identifier. I am able to do it only if i manually give a definite value to imei, the imei field is not being populated on its own by script. Also, i have commented the fields where i need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data into your SQL query like so:

```
$imei = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imei']);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sold WHERE imei = '$imei'");
```

Don't forget to escape string you get from a user with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.
Also don't forget to surround the $var in your query with single quotes `'` as shown. *(this is vital to make your code safe)*

If you use `mysql_query` in any other way you will be vulnerable to [SQL-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) attacks.

Comment: thank very much this helps but there's an error that its showing me Notice: Undefined index: imei in C:\xampp\htdocs\POS\v2\printsale.php on line 19 in my code first a script is updating the database and i need to pull out for pdf from database of the same imei value. Can you see how to bridge this?